# how to write aggregation filter using Sql (or SqlAlchemy)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a `trade` table in Postgres. The rows in the table essentially are transactions of stock buy/sell at a particular date/time combination.

```
trade_id   symbol       name      action      quantity      price      currency     date     time
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          AMZN         Amazon    BUY         5             1000       USD          2020-09-10  09:00
2          AMZN         Amazon    SELL        4             1050       USD          2020-09-11  08:00
3          AMZN         Amazon    BUY         5             900        USD          2020-09-12  12:00
4          FDX          Fedex     BUY         3             100        USD          2020-09-12  09:00
```

^ this is just an example dummy data for now.

I want to drive analytics on top of this `trade` table. The analytics I want to gather primarily are `holdings` & `pnl` (profit-&-loss) calculations.

The `pnl` will hold a diff of BUY->SELL. If a stock is BOUGHT, but never SOLD - then it won't reflect here. So the `pnl` results I would expect will look like this:

```
symbol    name      quantity     avg_buy    avg_sell        pnl      pnl_percentage
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AMZN      Amazon    4            1000       1050            50       5         # because only 4 shares were sold, we calculate PnL only for that
```

So the `holdings` results I would expect will look like this:

```
symbol    name      quantity     avg_price
------------------------------------------
AMZN      Amazon    6            916.67          # Math here is (1000*1 + 900*5 )/(1+5), the *1 comes from (5BUY - 4Sell)
FDX       Fedex     3            100
```

---

I am having a really hard time modeling this ^ with `sqlalchemy` (also having a hard time with pure SQL also) - mostly because I am not able to think of a clean way to write a neat query to get this going.

I need help trying to extract `pnl` & `holdings` out of `trade` table with `SQLAlchemy` or `SQL` query - and I am really lost on how to go about there. I was hoping to get some guidance or ideas in that sector from SQL gurus here. Thanks!

The way I am solving this today is with a `batch` job, which traverses this table row by row - and writes to a new table. I really don't want to be doing this as this can create inconsistencies and I have to run this `batch` job on cron and maintain it.

The way I have designed this with SQLAlchemy is like this (as I have built the APIs using Flask, the Flask SqlAlchemy is really nice for such work):

Model

```
from flask import jsonify
from models import db


class ModelTrade(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "trade"

    trade_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    symbol = db.Column(db.String(10), index=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), index=True, nullable=False)
    action = db.Column(db.Enum("BUY", "SELL", name="action"), nullable=False)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    currency = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    time = db.Column(db.Time, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, symbol, name, action, quantity, price, currency, date, time):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.name = name
        self.action = action
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price
        self.currency = currency
        self.date = date
        self.time = time

    def __repr__(self):
        return jsonify(
            {
                "trade_id": self.trade_id,
                "name": self.name,
                "symbol": self.symbol,
                "action": self.action,
                "quantity": self.quantity,
                "price": self.price,
                "currency": self.currency,
                "date": self.date,
                "time": self.time,
            }
        )
```

Schema

```
from schemas import ma
from marshmallow import fields


class SchemaTrade(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        # Fields to expose
        fields = [
            "trade_id",
            "action",
            "quantity",
            "price",
            "currency",
            "date",
            "time",
            "name",
            "symbol",
        ]


class SchemaTradeCreate(ma.Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    symbol = fields.Str()
    action = fields.Str()
    quantity = fields.Float()
    price = fields.Float()
    currency = fields.Str()
    date = fields.Str()
    time = fields.Str()

    class Meta:
        # Fields to expose
        fields = ["name", "symbol", "action", "quantity", "price", "currency", "date", "time"]
```

API

```
from flask import jsonify, request
from flask_cors import cross_origin
from flask_restful import Resource
import json
import marshmallow
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import extract
from config import Config
from models import db
from model_trade import ModelTrade
from schema_trade import SchemaTrade, SchemaTradeCreate


config_obj = Config()
schema_trade = SchemaTrade()
schema_trade_create = SchemaTradeCreate()


class ApiTrade(Resource):
    @cross_origin(origin="*")
    def get(self):
        page = request.args.get("page", 1, type=int)
        query_results = (
            ModelTrade.query.order_by(ModelTrade.date.desc())
            .order_by(ModelTrade.time.desc())
            .paginate(page, per_page=config_obj.get_pagination_results_count(), error_out=True)
        )
        results = [json.loads(schema_trade.dumps(query_result)) for query_result in query_results.items]
        return jsonify(
            {
                "count": len(results),
                "results": results,
                "page": page,
                "has_next": True if query_results.has_next else False,
                "has_prev": True if query_results.has_prev else False,
                "total_count": query_results.total,
                "total_pages": query_results.pages,
            }
        )
```

Comment: Please, if you are using **Postgresql** don´t tag as **MySql**. I removed the tag

Comment: Which selling strategy do you consider in your analytics, for example FIFO or LIFO? I.e. oldest stock sold first, or latest, or something else?